# Will Calling clear() on a vector of lists clear all the nodes in the list at each index?

Tags: c++, list, vector, hashtable

I am creating a hash table that has a private data member `vector<list<pair<K, V>>> hashTable;`. My understanding is that a rehash function should assign the elements of the original table to a temp table, empty the original table, resize it, the hash the elements of the temp table back into the original table.

Will an assignment such as `vector<list<pair<K,V>>> tempTable = origTable;` make a deep copy? Or do I need to declare `tempTable` to be the same size as original table and then go through each list at each index and add it to `tempTable`?

Finally, will calling `origTable.clear();` empty out all the nodes in each list at each index and reclaim the memory correctly or do I need to step through each index and explicitly empty each list?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention for types in C++ is to have copy semantics, and `std::vector`, `std::list` and `std::pair` all adhere to this.

Therefore `vector<list<pair<K,V>>> tempTable = origTable;` does a 'deep copy', and no reference to the old data is kept. And similarly calling `.clear()` on such a vector will destroy all used memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<list<pair<K,V>>> tempTable = origTable;
```

Everything will copy, from the vector, list, and pair all the way through to K and V.  However, it's worth considering that if K and/or V are themselves pointers, then the pointer will be copied but the object they point to will not, and you will have aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Copy assignment of vector is deep. The elements will be copied.

Calling `clear` will erase all elements from the standard vector. All of those objects are destroyed. The destructor of the standard iterator destroys all of its nodes.